# Relational Model for Nested Data

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

How should I set up the entities (tables) in the relational database for the following:

*"Each Experiment has one Strain. Strain can have many Experiments. **Each Strain has a Parent Strain which is a combination of one or more other Strains.**"*

Particularly I am struggling with how to assign the Parent Strain to the Strain.

Example:
Strain99 is a strain, whose parent strain usually will be Strain98 (but can also be a combination of ie Strain96, Strain197).
How should I go about designing the tables and relationships so each Strain will have a parent strain/s?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a many-to-many relationship.  "ParentStrain" would appear to be something different from a "Strain" -- its own entity.  It is a group of strains.  That suggests:

```
create table parentstrains (
    parentstrainid int generated always as identity primary key
);

create table parentstrainstrains (
    parentstrainstrainid int generated always as identity primary key,
    parentstrainid int not null references parentstrains(parentstrainid),
    strainid int not null references strains(strainid)
);
```

Then:

```
alter table strains add constraint fk_strains_parentstrains
    foreign key (parentstrainid) references parentstrains(parentstrainid);
```